# Parsing JSON Array Object in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to parse a JSON Object to insert values in table(MySQL). JSON is recived at server but it is unable to read the values to be inserted. Its inserting NULL values. 
Below is snapshot from my rails console.

```
Started POST "/lists.json" for 192.168.1.9 at 2013-08-13 11:38:46 +0530
  Processing by ListsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"list"=>[{"amount"=>"120", "status"=>"done", "itemno"=>"w01", "na
me"=>"t01"}]}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `lists` (`amount`, `itemno`, `name`, `status`) VALUES
 (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
   (103.0ms)  COMMIT
```

The Create method in my lists_controller.rb is as below

```
def create
    lists = params[:list].collect{|key,list_attributes| List.new(list_attributes)}
    all_list_valid = true
    lists.each_with_index do |list,index|
        unless list.valid?
            all_list_valid = false
            invalid_list = lists[index]
        end
    end

    if all_list_valid
        @lists = []
        lists.each do |list|
            list.save
            @lists << list
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list }
    else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

I am not sure why it is taking NULL values even though "Parameters" seems to have correct values. Please advise . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation for the [collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-collect) method.

```
irb(main):008:0> parameters = {"list"=>[{"amount"=>"120", "status"=>"done", "itemno"=>"w01", "name"=>"t01"}]}
=> {"list"=>[{"status"=>"done", "amount"=>"120", "itemno"=>"w01", "name"=>"t01"}]}
irb(main):009:0> parameters["list"]
=> [{"status"=>"done", "amount"=>"120", "itemno"=>"w01", "name"=>"t01"}]
irb(main):010:0> parameters["list"].collect{|list| p list}
{"status"=>"done", "amount"=>"120", "itemno"=>"w01", "name"=>"t01"}
=> [nil]
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I read the documentation and it seems that when I specify "key" its returning nil values                              irb(main):008:0> Parameters["list"].collect{|key,list| List.new(list)}
=> [#<List itemno: nil, name: nil, amount: nil, status: nil>]         but when I omit "key" it returns values                          irb(main):007:0> Parameters["list"].collect{|list| List.new(list)}
=> [#<List itemno: "w01", name: "t01", amount: "120", status: "done">] Now problem is its giving NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for ["itemno", "w01"]:Array) error

Comment: Give me a code. `stringify_keys` method only appnds to `Hash`, how you get an `Array` from `params[]`?